# templated code not working while non-templated code works!

Tags: c++, templates

I spent several hours, completely stuck when I realized that only the templated version of my code has a bug.

In the following code, when pushing_back elements in the `myMap`, the original vectors `myVec1` and `myVec2` are modified and contain garbage at the end of the execution. If I un-template everything, just replacing `template<T>` by double, then the code works fine as I would expect (the original arrays are untouched).

The funny thing is if I put a `cout` in the `copy constructor`, it does not get called if the code is templated. But it gets called if I replace the copy constructor with `Vector<T2>` by the original type `Vector<T>`, and then everything work fine.

Why wouldn't the compiler know that `T2==T` since I only use `double`?

(note, the code has been made as short as possible so as to show the errors - I thus removed accessors, made everything public etc.).

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>


template<class T>
class Vector{
public:
    Vector():n(0),data(0){};
    Vector(int N):n(N),data(new T[N]){};
    Vector(T x, T y):n(2),data(new T[2]){data[0]=x; data[1]=y;};
    template<class T2> Vector(const Vector<T2>& rhs):n(rhs.n), data(new T[n])
    {
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
            data[i] = T(rhs.data[i]);
    }   
    ~Vector(){delete[] data;}

    Vector& operator=(const Vector& rhs)
    {
        if (rhs.n != n)
        {
            if (data)
                delete[] data;
            data = new T[rhs.n];
        }
        n = rhs.n;
        memcpy(data, rhs.data, n*sizeof(T));
        return *this;
    }
    T& operator[](int i){return data[i];}
    const T& operator[](int i) const {return data[i];}
    int n;
    T* data;
};

typedef  Vector<double> Vectord;

template <class T> inline bool operator<(const Vector<T>& v1, const Vector<T>& v2)
{
    for (int i=0; i<v1.n; i++)
    {
        if (v1[i]<v2[i]) return true;
        if (v1[i]>v2[i]) return false;
    }
    return false;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::vector<Vectord> myVec1(3);
    myVec1[0] = Vectord(1.,3.);
    myVec1[1] = Vectord(3.,3.);
    myVec1[2] = Vectord(1.,5.);

    std::vector<Vectord> myVec2(3);
    myVec2[0] = Vectord(4.,1.);
    myVec2[1] = Vectord(2.,5.);
    myVec2[2] = Vectord(6.,5.);

    std::map<Vectord, std::vector<Vectord> > myMap;
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        myMap[myVec1[i]].push_back(myVec2[i]);
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should think it over if it's really a good idea to overload `operator<`, as this ordering does not represent any actual vector characteristics, thereby hurting the principle of least surprise. I suggest you rather declare it as a function `strictweakordering` and then give this to the `map`. (Though there are tons of examples where implementations, even stl ones, hurt this principle)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A templated constructor is never a copy constructor.

So your class is using the automatically generated copy constructor.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: Ooohh! Ok thanks!! I'll accept the answer in 3 minutes - as stackoverflow doesn't allow me to accept it before. Thanks!

Comment: quote from the standard (12.8/2, note 4):
Because a template constructor is never a copy constructor, the presence of such a template does not suppress the implicit declaration of a copy constructor. Template constructors participate in overload
resolution with other constructors, including copy constructors, and a template constructor may be used to copy an object if it provides a better match than other constructors.    _italic_ this link may be  helpful _italic_ http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/open/n2356/special.html